# indexing solr using jquery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, solr

## Is is possible to index (add/update) solr using jquery AJAX?

There is no example in net and I have been trying but no success.
Below is my code

```
 try {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://192.168.10.113:8080/solr/update/json?commit=true",
                data: { "add": { "doc": { "id": "222222", "name": "Ruby on Trails"}} },
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                crossDomain: true,
                jsonp: 'json.wrf',
                success: function (data) { alert(data); },
                failure: function (errMsg) {
                    alert(errMsg);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
```

My tomcat server log is mentioned below.
[`31/Oct/2012:15:56:24 +0530] "GET /solr/update/json?commit=true&json.wrf=jQuery1820996771614998579_1351662048057&add%5Bdoc%5D%5Bid%5D=222222&add%5Bdoc%5D%5Bname%5D=Ruby+on+Trails&_=1351678643653 HTTP/1.1" 200 159`

Though it says 200, the document is not added in solr. I have waited enough and repeated the process several times to remove the commit strategy of solr server being the culprit here. 
In chrome browser it says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < But that's too generic to take any guess.
It is some other issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using JSON.stringify to prepare JSON params, like this: `data: { "add": { "doc": JSON.stringify({ "id": "222222", "name": "Ruby on Trails"})}}`

Comment: Yes, I tried but the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to double check what you're actually doing. First, the uncaught exception in the browser is a bad sign since it will stop any javascript execution once raised. Even if you were doing the solr update succesfully you wouldn't see the success and error functions. Make sure you get rid of it before going any further. Secondly, you are doing a POST request and your log is showing a GET. Are you sure that log entry corresponds to the jQuery request?

Comment: Uncaught exception in browser could be because the solr server returns json instead of jsonp, which is most common explanation in this case. hence the question title is it possible.... I got rid of the success and error and the result is same... 3rd one is most interesting, yes the log entery is for this request and I don't know how it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. [This site](http://skipperkongen.dk/2011/01/11/solr-with-jsonp-with-jquery/) helped me out:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "...",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'json.wrf',
    data: {
      q: "tag:" + request.term + "*"
    },
...
```